# PHP Contact Form for Bootstrap

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I have trouble with php contact form on Bootstrap. I don't know where is problem. It always gives error message. I replaced my e-mail address there but it still gives error. I don't know which line to change.

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
 empty($_POST['email'])         ||
empty($_POST['phone'])      ||
empty($_POST['message'])    ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'info@balkescafequiz.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail:      $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@balkescafequiz.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: Post your error message in the question

Comment: There is a Javascript code ( http://balkescafequiz.com/code.txt ). And I see error message 'Su an kayit kapali gibi gorunuyor. Dog...' as you can see in the code.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt read trough your script, but try use this:

```
    //Clean string before sending
   function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
  }

  //build message
  $email_message .= "$l_firstname: ".clean_string($FirstName)."\n";
  $email_message .= "$l_lastname: ".clean_string($LastName)."\n";
  $email_message .= "$l_email: ".clean_string($Email)."\n";
  $email_message .= "$l_phone: ".clean_string($Phone)."\n";
  $email_message .= "$l_msg: ".clean_string($Message)."\n";


  $email_subject = "New Mail From "."$FullName";


  // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: '."$FullName".'<'.$Email.'>'."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$Email."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  mail($Recipient, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

  //return to index, show confirmation
  header("Location: index.php?lang=$Language&show=success");
```

This is what i use :)